# Azure AD B2C Supported Applications

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I'm considering using Azure AD B2C to authenticate users for my ASP.NET Core app with React front-end as well as native apps built in Xamarin.

My research raised a few question marks:

1. Both the web/React app and native apps are the same application. They must use the same App ID and tap into the same user database. Is this the case?
2. A video on Channel 9 suggested that Azure AD B2C assumes users will have shorter sessions - as opposed to enterprise users longer sessions. Not sure how to interpret this. What is a short session and how long is its max limit?
3. Is it safe to assume that an authenticated user's token will return a `GUID` value to identifiy the user e.g. UserId? Or is the ID of a different type?
4. Do native app users sign in through the built-in browser or directly from the app? I think, having to switch to the built-in browser may produce a degraded user experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The web and native apps can be registered as the same application or they can be registered as different applications but, either way, they share the same directory of users.
2. The Channel 9 video is referring to the end-user visit, not the application session, if this is how you interpreted it. Azure AD B2C provides you with control of lifetimes of tokens, lifetimes of sessions, and the single sign-on behavior across different applications and multiple policies in the same tenant. Configuration of, and scenarios for use of, these lifetime controls are described at [Azure Active Directory B2C: Token, session and single sign-on configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-token-session-sso).
3. The ID token that is issued for a user contains a `sub` (subject) claim that is set to the object identifier for the user. This object identifier is formatted as a GUID string. The ID token is described at [Azure AD B2C: Token reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-tokens).
4. Currently, a native app must sign users in through the system browser, because Azure AD B2C does not support the [resource owner password credential grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3) (however [work has started on a prototype of this grant](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/13817784-add-support-for-resource-owner-password-credential)). Authentication libraries, such as [AppAuth for Android](https://openid.github.io/AppAuth-Android/), [AppAuth for iOS](https://openid.github.io/AppAuth-iOS/), and [Microsoft Authentication Library for .NET](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet) implement the browser integration for you. They also implement "the [best current practice](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8252.txt) [which] is to perform the OAuth authorization request in an external user agent (typically the browser) rather than an embedded user agent (such as one implemented with web-views)."